# Redewendung: vor den Kopf stoßen

Tags: idiom

Warum sagt man "vor" in der Redewendung jemand(en) vor den Kopf stoßen?
Irgendwie kommt mir das "vor" unlogisch vor.

Comment: "Vor das Schienbein treten" entspricht demselben Muster, es handelt sich als um keinen Einzelfall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Vor (oder für) den Kopf stoßen" ist noch in Quellen der deutschen Klassik synonym mit *"auf den Kopf schlagen"*. Da "Kopf" auch "Stirn" bedeuten konnte, kann man sich darunter auch einen Schlag an (oder vor) die Stirn vorstellen. "Vor den Kopf" wurde auch zusammen mit "schießen" offenbar statt "in den Kopf" gebraucht, wie ein Goethe-Zitat im [Grimmschen Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK10659) zeigt ("paff! schosz ihn einer vorn kopf").

"Jemanden vor den Kopf stoßen" bzw. "...schlagen" wurde aber gleichzeitig bereits als Redewendung für "verdutzt, ängstlich machen, abschrecken, beleidigen" etc. verwendet.

Es handelt sich also um eine stehende Redewendung, die eine heute altertümliche Form konserviert hat.